# How to disable html date input type in choosing future dates?

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, datepicker

I have a code and just last year, it was still working. What it does is that it disables user to pick future dates. Now that it's January, it doesn't seem to be working. I do not understand why. Please help me fix this. Your help will be appreciated.

This is the input:

```
<input id="reqDate" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="reqDate" required="required" type="date">
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          var input = document.getElementById("reqDate");
          var today = new Date();
          var day = today.getDate();

          // Set month to string to add leading 0
          var mon = new String(today.getMonth()+1); //January is 0!
          var yr = today.getFullYear();

            if(mon.length < 2) { mon = "0" + mon; }

            var date = new String( yr + '-' + mon + '-' + day );

          input.disabled = false; 
          input.setAttribute('max', date);
</script>
```

By the way, I am using this code in a .php file.

Answer (score 0):

Like you have used, the native `input[type="date"]` element supports a maximum date value:

```
Enter a date before 1980-01-01:
<input type="date" name="bday" max="1979-12-31">
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp
```

The JavaScript you are using to set the date does not zero-pad the day, so for the first of January, you would get the date max="2016-01-1". To keep with your JavaScript version, sero pad the date with:

```
<script>
      var input = document.getElementById("reqDate");
      var today = new Date();
      var day = today.getDate();

      // Set month to string to add leading 0
      var mon = new String(today.getMonth()+1); //January is 0!
      var yr = today.getFullYear();

        if(mon.length < 2) { mon = "0" + mon; }
        if(day.length < 2) { dayn = "0" + day; }

        var date = new String( yr + '-' + mon + '-' + day );

      input.disabled = false; 
      input.setAttribute('max', date);
</script>
```

With this being a PHP script, to simplify your code you could use:

```
<input type="date" name="bday" max="<?=date('Y-m-d')?>">
```

N.B. Support for `input[type="date"]` varies between browsers (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime).

You can confirm the max value used is in the correct supported RCF3339 format by inspecting the element in the browser inspector.

Comment: You'll still want to verify the date is in range on the server side.  (1) Because not all browsers support` <input date>` and some that do don't support the `max` attribute. (2) Because evil actors can submit any value they want.

Comment: `<?=` is the equivalent of `<?php echo`, you might need to use that instead if short-tags are not supported. Also, **never trust user input**, so do as @JohnHascall here said and validate the data in PHP/server-side too.

Comment: the `max` attribute is already used/set in the code the OP shared.

Comment: maybe you need to add a zero before days too, just like with month. Did you check the value actually added to the input field in the generated HTML?

Comment: Replace `var day = today.getDate();` with `var day = new String(today.getDate());`  And then `if (day.length < 2) { day = "0" + day; }` will work to zero-pad the day-of-the-month.

Comment: Glad you understood my adjustments

Comment: this will support in typescript?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using min attribute in the input. In html5 we can specify min or max attributres in proper date format YYYY-MM-DD